# How can I get frontend query parameter after hashbang (like in google search)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react application and I have two URLs such as the followings:

- `/home`
- `/athletes`

I want to add a `q` parameter after a hashbang in both of these URLs. So, this URL basically brings search results in whatever page I am in:

- `/home#q=test`
- `/athletes#q=test`

I have setup the structure that allows me to achieve this. However, I don't know how to get the "query parameter" after the hash. How can I get this? I am using html5 history api for my urls.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google search doesn't use hashtag. It uses the traditional `?q=foo`. Hashtag was made to scroll to a particular element, but some web apps such as Google Play now use it for JavaScript queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the hash via `window.location.hash`.

Also you can attach an event handler for hash changes: `window.addEventListener('hashchange', callback)`